# NameError: uninitialized constant on seed.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

While doing the seed.rb for my app I came across the following error when running `rake db:seed`:

```
rake aborted!
NameError: uninitialized constant Menu::CourseMenu
C:in `destroy_all'
C:.../db/seeds.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => db:seed
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Menu:

```
class Menu < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :course_menus, dependent: :destroy
end
```

CoursesMenu:

```
class CoursesMenu < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :menu
  has_and_belongs_to_many :recipes, dependent: :destroy
end
```

Seed.rb:

```
# This file should contain all the record creation needed to seed the database with its default values.
# The data can then be loaded with the rake db:seed (or created alongside the db with db:setup).
#
# Examples:
#
#   cities = City.create([{ name: 'Chicago' }, { name: 'Copenhagen' }])
#   Mayor.create(name: 'Emanuel', city: cities.first)


User.destroy_all
Menu.destroy_all
CookBook.destroy_all
CoursesMenu.destroy_all
Recipe.destroy_all



User.create! [
  { email: "jean@mail.com", password: "12345", status: true },
  { email: "wendy@mail.com", password: "12345", status: true  },
  { email: "jose@mail.com", password: "12345", status: true  },
  { email: "vivi@mail.com", password: "12345", status: true  },
  { email: "emilio@mail.com", password: "12345", status: true  }
]

sample_menus = Menu.create! [
  { name: "For Mom", description: "Menu to lose weight" },
  { name: "For Dad", description: "Menu to gain more muscle" },
  { name: "For the lil tykes", description: "Menu so they stop being fat" },
  { name: "For the Vegan Aunt", description: "For the old harpy" }
]

sample_cookbooks = CookBook.create! [
  { name: "Jean'selections", description: "Premiun choices by Jean" },
  { name: "Wendy'selections", description: "Premiun choices by Wendy" },
  { name: "Jose'selections", description: "Premiun choices by Jose" },
  { name: "Best of All", description: "JPremiun choices by the Crew" }
]

sample_recipes = Recipe.create! [
  { img_url: "http://static.food2fork.com/BrownieFeature193f.jpg", title: "Slutty Brownies", source_url: "http://whatsgabycooking.com/slutty-brownies/"},
  { img_url: "http://static.food2fork.com/pizza292x2007a259a79.jpg", title: "Homemade Pizza", source_url: "http://www.simplyrecipes.com/recipes/homemade_pizza/" },
  { img_url: "http://static.food2fork.com/5337400468_d5892f3a03_od5cd.jpg", title: "Chicken Tortilla Soup", source_url: "http://thepioneerwoman.com/cooking/2011/01/chicken-tortilla-soup/"},
  { img_url: "http://static.food2fork.com/GuacamoleGrilledCheese6019.jpg", title: "Guacamole Grilled Cheese Sandwich", source_url: "http://www.twopeasandtheirpod.com/guacamole-grilled-cheese-sandwich/"}
]


sample_courses_menus = CoursesMenu.create! [

  { course_name: "Breakfast", day: "Monday" },
  { course_name: "Day Snack", day: "Monday" },
  { course_name: "Lunch", day: "Monday" },
  { course_name: "Dinner", day: "Monday" },
  { course_name: "Night Snack", day: "Monday" },

  { course_name: "Breakfast", day: "Tuesday" },
  { course_name: "Day Snack", day: "Tuesday" },
  { course_name: "Lunch", day: "Tuesday" },
  { course_name: "Dinner", day: "Tuesday" },
  { course_name: "Night Snack", day: "Tuesday" },

  { course_name: "Breakfast", day: "Wednesday" },
  { course_name: "Day Snack", day: "Wednesday" },
  { course_name: "Lunch", day: "Wednesday" },
  { course_name: "Dinner", day: "Wednesday" },
  { course_name: "Night Snack", day: "Wednesday" },

  { course_name: "Breakfast", day: "Thursday" },
  { course_name: "Day Snack", day: "Thursday" },
  { course_name: "Lunch", day: "Thursday" },
  { course_name: "Dinner", day: "Thursday" },
  { course_name: "Night Snack", day: "Thursday" },

  { course_name: "Breakfast", day: "Friday " },
  { course_name: "Day Snack", day: "Friday " },
  { course_name: "Lunch", day: "Friday " },
  { course_name: "Dinner", day: "Friday " },
  { course_name: "Night Snack", day: "Friday " },

  { course_name: "Breakfast", day: "Saturday" },
  { course_name: "Day Snack", day: "Saturday" },
  { course_name: "Lunch", day: "Saturday" },
  { course_name: "Dinner", day: "Saturday" },
  { course_name: "Night Snack", day: "Saturday" },

  { course_name: "Breakfast", day: "Sunday" },
  { course_name: "Day Snack", day: "Sunday" },
  { course_name: "Lunch", day: "Sunday" },
  { course_name: "Dinner", day: "Sunday" },
  { course_name: "Night Snack", day: "Sunday" }
]


sample_cookbooks. << 20.times { |index| CookBook.create! name: "CookBook#{index}", description: "This is a cookbook sample #{index}" }



CoursesMenu.all.each do |course_menu|
  course_menu.recipes = sample_recipes.sample
  course_menu.save!
end

Menu.all.each do |menu|
  menu.course_menus = sample_courses_menus.sample
  menu.save!
end

CookBook.all.each do |book|
  book.recipes = sample_recipes.sample
  book.save!
end

User.all.each do |user|
  user.cook_books = sample_cookbooks.sample
  user.menus = sample_menus.sample
  user.save!
end
```

I suspect there is something I'm handling wrong with the relationship because if I change `destroy_all` to `delete_all` in the seed.rb this particular error doesn't occur.

I was hopping someone could point me in the right direction to solve this.

Comment: Show the `seed.rb` file, the error is there it seems.

Comment: @Iceman I've added the seed.rb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `Menu` model, change

```
has_many :course_menus, dependent: :destroy
```

to

```
has_many :courses_menus, dependent: :destroy
```

Would it be a more correct inflection to define the `CoursesMenu` as `CourseMenu`? If so your association would be correct as is.

Also, FYI, the reason `destroy_all` fails and `delete_all` works is because `destroy_all` deletes each record individually, executing callbacks (including `dependent: :destroy`s) in the process. This is where the error occurs because Rails tries to use a model of type `CourseMenu` which doesn't exist the way you have defined your classes. In contrast, `delete_all` simply deletes the records in question, in one query (`DELETE from menus`), and does not try to execute any callback code, so Rails never encounters the mis-named resource.

Comment: Thanks for both the explanation and the help. I found other errors in the seed but I'll try to work on those on my own first.

Answer (score 2):

## Problem

`Menu` has many `:course_menus`

but your class is

```
CoursesMenu
```

## Solution

You could just rename `CoursesMenu` to `Course`, and `Menu` would have many `:courses`.

Whatever you choose, you could check the names are correct :

```
:courses.to_s.capitalize.singularize
#=> "Course"
:course_menus.to_s.camelcase.singularize
#=> "CourseMenu"
```